# shortcut key for show applications in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Linux for the first time and I want to know if there is any shortcut key for the "show applications" button. I've searched, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: What should that button do? What window manager are you using?

Comment: What's about https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072043/keyboard-shortcut-to-show-applications?

Comment: Super + A worked, Tks guys ^^

Answer (score 2):

*Ubuntu 20.04*

Hit Super-key, type "set" and then select ...
Settings > Keyboard shortcuts > type "show" in the search field
... you will see:

`Show all applications: Super+A`
... among other things.